# How to Set AutocompleteTextview and its adapter inside each recyclerView Item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I want to set up a `RecyclerView` with each `RecyclerView` item having an `AutocompletetextView` and an `ImageButton` and on click of a button on the main UI, the item should be added and the user can enter relevant data into the `AutoCompleteTextView` and autocomplete suggestion should show while he is typing in it .

```
public class SensorListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SensorListAdapter.SensorListViewHolder>  {



    List<CrateSensors> crateSensorsList;
    List<String> TagStrings;



    public SensorListAdapter(List<CrateSensors> crateSensorsList) {
        this.crateSensorsList = crateSensorsList;
    }



    public class SensorListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        AutoCompleteTextView mBarcode ; ImageButton mBarcodeImageButton;
        ArrayAdapter mTagArrayAdapter;

        public SensorListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mBarcode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Sensor_List_Enterbarcode_AutoCompleteTextView);
            mBarcodeImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Sensor_List_Enterbarcode_ImageButton);


            mTagArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( itemView.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,TagStrings);
            mBarcode.setAdapter(mTagArrayAdapter);
            mBarcode.setThreshold(1);
            mBarcode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mBarcode.showDropDown();
                }
            });


        }
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SensorListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sensor_item ,parent,false);
        return new SensorListViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SensorListViewHolder holder, int position) {

        CrateSensors crateSensors = crateSensorsList.get(position);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return crateSensorsList.size();
    }


}
```

Comment: whats wrong? nothing shows  when typing ?

Comment: TagStrings is not inialized, is that?

Comment: @P.Juni I'm able to add each item into the recyclerView, but the problem is when I click on the AutoCompleteTextview of each item the app crashes. I feel the adapter for the AutoCompleteTextView  is not set the right way and I can't figure it out how

Comment: @DmytroBatyuk I'm passing the Tagstring while I'm creating the constructor for the Adapter Class, I feel the Context that I'm passing to the adapter is wrong , im not sure why the application crashes

Comment: You are passing crateSensorsList but not TagStrings

Comment: whats the crash message ?

Comment: @DmytroBatyuk my bad on the next iteration of code I have passed it, I did not update the code here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @P.Juni Fatal Error: Main. Application Forced closed

Comment: I meant frm the logcat

Comment: @DarshanM have you got any solution for this case?